# how to remove line in UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Help remove the line in tab bar!

[image]

```
`[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];`  - NOT WORK
```

CODE:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:54.0f/255.0f green:62.0f/255.0f blue:69.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];


    [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barMap.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barMapNo.png"]];

    [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barNews.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barNewsNo.png"]];

    [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barNew.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barNewNo.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to remove the `shadowImage` then just do the same thing you're doing, but assign it to shadowImage instead of `backgroundImage`.

Comment: This, but I've found that (as of iOS 7) using `[[UIImage alloc] init]` isn't sufficient. I draw a 1px transparent image using CG and convert that to a UIImage to use.

Comment: @axiixc have you ever tried setting it to `nil`?  It's been a while since I've messed with this and I remember that I got a one liner to work at one point.

Comment: can't say, but my gut would have me believe that would just use the default appearance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes you're setting an image to a tab bar item (with default frame) when the image is larger than the button's frame. You need to replace the entire button!

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[tabBar setItems:@[ barButton, /* etc */ ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Here is apple guideline for shadow image.

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).